# selenium python 2.7 getting URL from scripts error

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

while run the script fire fox is launched correctly,but it is not getting the URL,Even i upgrade all like selenium,pip,fire fox too..give me a solution.how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

You make sure you add http:// to your URL.